# How to get the underlying Stream handle from an Apache NMS ActiveMQ message

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, nms, apache-nms

**Background:**
C# WPF application talking to JAVA server running on linux via ActiveMQ(Apache.NMS) / JSON(Newtonsoft.Json)

**Problem**:
JSON messages greater than 85000 bytes lead to LOH fragmentation

**Possible solution:**
Instead of reading the JSON as an Apache.NMS.ITextMessage (which is currently the case), 
get the underlying stream handle and deserialize using JsonTextReader

**Implementation issues:**
It would appear that this is not supported by Apache.NMS API although
there are ActiveMQStreamMessage/ActiveMQBytesMessage variants which
doesn't really fit the bill here.

I would like to know if anybody has got any experience on above?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you agree to skip the "pure" NMS api and access the ActiveMQ classes, you can get a handle to a MemoryStream via the public Content property. There may be compression you need to deal with though.

```
                    ITextMessage msg = consumer.Receive () as ITextMessage;
                    ActiveMQTextMessage tmsg = msg as ActiveMQTextMessage;
                    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(tmsg.Content);

                    if(tmsg.Compressed == true)
                    {
                        stream = tmsg.Connection.CompressionPolicy.CreateDecompressionStream(stream);                            
                    }

                    // TODO read MemoryStream to whatever
```